# $location.path not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular application. For redirection i am using $location.path.

Its working fine in chrome/Firefox but not at all in IE(Internet Explorer).

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Answer (score 0):

$location.path is not the preferred solution.. 
Try using `$state.go`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:
 $window.location.href= "Your URL"

Comment: Then you must go with $state.go() Or either go with console trace for $location.path or $window.location.href in browser